# Randomization for Regression with missing data

Tags: regression

I have about 1500 cases with 400 missing rows from variables to variables.  I want to randomly select 200 cases for regression so I purposely select the valid cases out from the spreadsheet without missing data.... then I randomly select 200 cases to run.  Does it violate the randomization in this case? Or I must have to select all cases with missing data for randomization need? Thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it depends on which kind of missing data you have.

If the missing data points have some significant implications, you should not exclude them from the outset. You should include them by methods such as interpolation.

But if they are not important, you could exclude them from the dataset and perform random selection.

In other words, if the missing itself is a sort of signal, include them and if it is just a random noise, exclude them.